# Can I validate a model by a relationship to another property?

Tags: validation, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model for a tour, which has a beginning and an ending:

```
this.model = db.define('Tour', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    from_time: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    },
    to_time:  {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that `to_time` is after `from_time`?

(I guess `validate` can be used, but I don't know how)

Comment: I know the `isAfter` and `isBefore` preset validators exists, but don't know if can be used to check other model fields.

Comment: Just confirmed with sequelize devs, the way to do it is with a custom validator, like @alexpods pointed out.

Comment: Just one caveat, if you want to do some overkill validation like `start < end` plus `end > start` (read: check both fields at the same time in each field declaration), maybe the custom validator have to be set on the model definition, just like the long&lat example in the docs.

Answer (score 7):

`this` in validatar will reference to the current model. So it can be written like:

```
// ...
to_time: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: true,
    validate: {
        isAfterFrom: function(toTime) {
            if (this.fromTime > toTime) {
                throw new Error('To time must be less then from time')
            }
        }
    }
},
// ...
```